# Overlap Item Gridview Android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm implementing the UI like the picture below. I'm using gridview to this layout. When user tap the item in gird. It show a circle overlap to the other item. I don't how to do it. at first I define a layout with the circle is gone and add onclicklistener. If user tap on that, I visible the circle, but the size of gridview also extend. Can you help me provide solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this views in gridview parent layout preferable relative layout. You must add them after your grid view initsialisaton is done and onitemclick listener on grid item to make them visible. Exactly the one you've tryed but not in grid view but in the activity rootlayour.

Comment: Use frameLayout to place one layout to another

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It is a good solution, but I also support drag drop in this view, I think It's too much event so I think if we use another layout the code is too complex